# Opening file in a directory error "Cannot find file. Verify the path and file name are correct."

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a requirement to open all the .MSG files from a directory.

This code is working

```
Sub GetMSG()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
inPath = "C:\Users\Krishna\Desktop\Test\"
MsgBox inPath
thisFile = LCase(Dir(inPath & "\*.msg"))
MsgBox thisFile
Do While thisFile <> ""

    Set Msg = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem(inPath & thisFile)

    Msg.Display

    thisFile = Dir
Loop
```

Below code fails (I need to use a file browser for my requirement)

```
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

Dim oShell As Object
Dim olApp As Object

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder with attachments", 0)

If oShell Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Folder was not selected", vbCritical: Exit Sub

FldPth = oShell.self.Path

thisFile = LCase(Dir(FldPth & "\*.msg"))
MsgBox thisFile
Do While thisFile <> ""

    Set Msg = olApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(FldPth & thisFile)

    Msg.Display

    thisFile = Dir
Loop
```

Error
[image]

I am able to open all the files when I hard code the location. I am getting an error with Shell Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the path separator is missing in `Set Msg = olApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(FldPth & thisFile)`, add it and see if it works.

Comment: @JK207, I added the path separator like below but getting syntax error                               
                                                                                                                              'Set Msg = olApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(FldPth & thisFile),'

Comment: Sorry, should have made it more clear, by path separator I meant a "\" between `FldPth` and `thisFile`, i.e. `Set Msg = olApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(FldPth & "\" & thisFile)`. When something isn't working, it's always a good idea to use `Debug.Print` statement (where possible) to print the expression to Immediate Window and examine it.